# Toggle icons in accordion when clicking header

Tags: jquery, html

I have a footer with links, that when in mobile view, the links are hidden.
[image]

When the user clicks a header, the links should toggle down, and the icon next to the header should change from a plus to minus icon. As seen here, that isn't working.

[image]

When the user clicks the expanded header again, the section collapses and the icon should return to a plus sign.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="footer-links">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="panel-heading panel-columns panel">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#about" data-parent="#accordion">
            Header
          </a>
        </h4>
        <ul class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg collapse" id="about">
          <li><a href="">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-heading panel-columns panel">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#why" data-parent="#accordion">
            Header
          </a>
        </h4>
        <ul class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg collapse" id="why">
          <li><a href="">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-heading panel-columns panel">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#quicklinks" data-parent="#accordion">
            Header
          </a>
        </h4>
        <ul class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg collapse" id="quicklinks">
          <li><a href="">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-offer-columns">
        <h4 class="deal-text"><strong>Ad text will</strong> go here</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-share-columns">
        <div class="footer-share">
          <a href=""><img src="/img/facebook_icon.png"></a>
          <a href=""><img src="/img/twitter_icon.png"></a>
          <a href=""><img src="/img/linkedin_icon.png"></a>
          <a href=""><img src="/img/youtube_icon.png"></a>
          <a href=""><img src="/img/google_icon.png"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.panel-heading').on('click', '.accordion-toggle', function (){
$(".accordion-toggle").each(function(){
  console.log($("this"));
  $(this).removeClass('visibility-status');
  console.log('open');
});

$(this).toggleClass('visibility-status');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.accordion-toggle:after {
  content: '\E145';
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
}
.accordion-toggle.visibility-status:after {
  content: '\E15B';
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Hard code the class you want to add first, then just do two `toggleClass` calls like so:

```
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.zmdi-minus').toggleClass('zmdi-plus').toggleClass('zmdi-minus');
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.zmdi-plus').toggleClass('zmdi-plus').toggleClass('zmdi-minus');
});
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/nt4q2q29/**

**Edit:**

(Based on your comment), we can make it much simpler as well:

```
$('.accordion-toggle').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('.zmdi').toggleClass('zmdi-plus').toggleClass('zmdi-minus');
});
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/nt4q2q29/3/**

**Edit 2:**

Material Icons seems to require you to place the icon between the tags rather than as a class, so I've modified the code a little using jQuery's `html()`, and check for the hard-coded class I've added to the markup, `add` in this case, which we check for and then add content conditionally. Lastly we toggle the class:

```
$('.accordion-toggle').on('click', function() {
    var $icon = $(this).find('.material-icons');

    if ($icon.hasClass('add')) {
        $icon.html('&#xE15B;');
    } else {
        $icon.html('&#xE145;');
    }

    $icon.toggleClass('add');
});
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/h2r83ps9/**

Comment: This is closer, but need the icon to trigger as soon as the user clicks, not wait until the collapse state is shown. I tried changing `shown.bs.collapse` to 'click', but that doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, you can change `shown.bs.collapse` to 'click' but then you need to also change the selector to work on the element being clicked (see my edit.)

Comment: I've adjusted my markup, but can't get the class to toggle. I'm using material icons font (https://design.google.com/icons/), not zmdi. https://jsfiddle.net/q61uhcv7/1/

Comment: Please see my last edit. I think I've got it now. And if you don't want to add anything to the markup you can place the `toggleClass` before the `if else` statement and it will work just the same.

Comment: Thanks for helping out with this. I think this might be a clearer way to explain what I'm trying to get to: http://jsfiddle.net/kx22wgno/

The bottom navigation is what my markup is, and I need it to function like the accordion nav above it(without changing the markup). It starts out collapsed on load(though currently loading expanded) if in mobile mode(desktop is completely open and spread out). If one section is open, and the user opens another, the previous opened section should close, only allowing one section to be open at a time. 

Hopefully this clears up the idea.

Comment: Oh, you didn't mention that in your question. I thought you were only having issue with the plus/minus icons. You might want to edit your question to reflect exactly what you're having a problem with. As it stands it's not entirely clear.

Comment: I updated the question and my code to better reflect the current state and the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it toggle by doing the following:

```
//When the user clicks on the header/or any other div where you want to display toggle data
$('IdOfTheDivInHeader').click(function(){
 $('IdOfTheDivYouWantToDisplayOnToggle').toggle();
});
```

You can also read more about the jquery [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method

Hope that helps you!

Comment: The idea is to toggle between to icons (a plus and a minus) when the user clicks one of the headers. So you start out with a plus icon showing, click a header, and the minus icon shows.

Comment: I have just added a button to show the feature that I was talking about above: http://plnkr.co/edit/JvS7B6eK1nAU09ks5SA1?p=preview. You can try doing the same on your header.

Comment: Yes, that's a basic toggle. I'm talking about toggling the icon of the header, not just the content of a div it controls.

Comment: Made the changes you suggested. Try this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/m6kh9wlCmWgWa2WVBO6D?p=preview. It is toggling between icons. I hope this is what you wanted.